# C++arithmetic inner manipulations

Tags: c++, rounding

I am trying to do some precision calculations and I am interested in learning, how `C++` (in my case), performs arithmetic manipulations internaly.
Say that we have the following program (I am just gonna write the body since it is not meant for actually running it)

```
double x = 1./3.;
double y = 0.12345;

double z = 9.* y + x*x;
```

What I am thinking, is that `C++`, takes `x` and stores somewhere in memory the closest binary representation that yields the (closest to) value `1./3.`. Same for `y`.
But what happens with `z`? Is it doing addition/multiplication after it has represented all numbers/variables that take place, in their corresponding closest binary representation? Or something else happens.
I welcome any reference that could shed light into my question.

Comment: [What every programmer should know about floating-point arithmetic, html version](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html); [pdf version](https://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf)

Comment: A good way of understanding how this all works is to look at the generated assembly code. The variables will temporarily be stored in CPU register and manipulated there.

Comment: Practically, that's up to the compiler, and how it handles your code as a whole.   If the compiler can detect that `x` and `y` are never modified after initialisation, it way well calculate the value used to initialise `z` directly.    If `x`, `y`, and `z` are never subsequently used in your code, the compiler may even discard all of them, so the values are never stored anywhere.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I am more worried about *when* the change base_10 -> base_2 happens. That way, I can (probably) track the rounding error (of course in easy calculations).

Answer (score 1):

Computers use something called IEEE754 standard to represent floating point values (double and floats). You can read more about that standard online. And for your question, c++ compiler does something like this- first it stores number 9.0 somewhere in memory, than it reads value of variable y, multiplies those two numbers and store them in some temporary variable (lets call it tmp0). Than, it multiplies x by x, and stores that again in the temporary variable (lets call it tmp1), and than after that, it adds tmp0 and tmp1 to the variable z, and deletes tmp0 and tmp1 from memory. And yes, if that is your answer, it does first store all those variables somewhere in memory, and only after that he can evaluate the value of z.